# Create device-independent bitmap without allocating memory

Tags: winapi, gdi, freeimage, hbitmap

This is what I currenty do to load images in my application:

```
auto b = ::FreeImage_Load(type, path.c_str());
void *bits;

auto hbmp = CreateDIBSection(
    dc,
    FreeImage_GetInfo(bitmap),
    DIB_RGB_COLORS,
    &bits,
    0,
    0
);

std::memcpy(bits, FreeImage_GetBits(b), size);
```

It works very well, but I'd like to avoid allocating memory twice - `::FreeImage_Load` already stores data in a way that's suitable for dib. Is there a way of calling `CreateDIBSection` that would prevent allocation and would force dib created that way to use buffer provided by me? If not, is there another method that would allow that?

It seems that providing `NULL` instead of `**ppvBits` prevents allocation - is there a way to modify buffer address later? I've also tried tinkering with `hSection` parameter but dibs created that way were incorrect.

Comment: `hSection` is the way to do it. What do you mean they were incorrect?

Comment: @JonathanPotter OK, thank you, I'll try again in such case. I couldn't display them on my hdc. Maybe I've used `CreateFileMappingA` incorrectly?

Comment: What is the purpose of creating device-independent bitmap `hbmp`?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT ddbs have some limitations, e.g. max size is limited, it also has to got the same depth as device you're going to display it on. But the best thing about dibs is that you can freely edit their buffers

Comment: Yes, if you need different depths, only use `CreateDIBSection`. You can refer to another link.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I didn't get your idea wrong.

Maybe you can use `CreateDIBitmap` to convert `FreeImage` images to `HBITMAP`.

```
FIBITMAP *dib = FreeImage_Load(type, path.c_str());
// ...
HBITMAP bitmap = CreateDIBitmap(hDC, FreeImage_GetInfoHeader(dib),

CBM_INIT, FreeImage_GetBits(dib), FreeImage_GetInfo(dib), DIB_RGB_COLORS);

// ...
FreeImage_Unload(dib);
```

Related Link: [How do I convert a FreeImage image to a HBITMAP ?](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

If you want to use `CreateDIBSection`, you can use a non-null `hSection` argument and use `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFileEx()` to create the section, the latter's `lpBaseAddress` should point to your bits.

Remember to fully initialize the parameters in `MapViewOfFileEx` and `CreateFileMapping`.

Here is a similar discussion you can refer: [How to create an HBITMAP wrapping an existing byte buffer?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/457e532b-6d24-41b8-a4ff-a433537cce71/how-to-create-an-hbitmap-wrapping-an-existing-byte-buffer?forum=winforms)